# Calculate the square root only using ++

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

Your task is to calculate the square root of a positive integer without using any mathematical operators to change the number, such as:

- Setting a variable (ex. squareRoot = 5)
- Addition (A+B)
- Subtraction (A-B)
- Multiplication (A*B)
- Division (A/B)
- Square, cube, fourth, etc. roots
- Exponents

Comparison operators (such as <, >, ==, etc) are not considered "mathematical operators" for the purposes of this question and are allowed as long as they do not change the value of a variable.

The only operator that you are able to use is ++.  The following exceptions are in place:

- If you wish, you may initialize a variable by setting it to 0.
- If your language does not include the ++ syntax, you may use an equivalent syntax, such as foo+=1 or foo=foo+1
- The square root should be calculated to at least 6 digits beyond the decimal (the hundred-thousands place) and outputted as a whole number of the decimals (ex. if I input 2 it could come out as 14142135624 or 1414213 depending on the rounding).  Rounding up or down is not important.

User-defined functions are not allowed.  In addition, simulating functions with goto is not allowed as well.

I'm interested to see what everyone submits!  Happy coding!

### CLARIFICATION

Clarify that number is a positive integer.  You are welcome to make code that would do any number but it is not necessary.

### CLARIFICATION #2

Clarify that comparison operators are allowed.

### CLARIFICATION #3

Addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and functions to change numbers are not allowed **at all**, regardless of whether they are saved to a variable or not.  I'm sorry that this invalidates a couple existing answers, but I meant to define this group of operators with "change the number" in order to prevent troll answers (ex. I just used the sqrt() function, you only prohibited addition, multiplication, division, and subtraction).  Sorry for the confusion.

### CLARIFICATION #4

Clarify that we need at least 5 digits.  10 digits caused code to run for a long time.

Comment: Are comparisons such as `<` and `>` disallowed operators?

Comment: Comparisons are fine, however the only operation that can change the value of a variable (or constant, I suppose) are ++ and --, with the exceptions listed above.

Comment: Are bitwise operators allowed? And to clarify, is -- allowed or not... as it isn't stated in the question, but in your comment you mentioned it.

Comment: Nope, -- is not allowed, sorry for the confusion!  I originally planned to have ++ and -- but I decided to take -- out at the last minute.

Comment: @iggyvolz ... and bitwise?

Comment: _"without using any mathematical operators to change the number"_ - I think this might need clarification. Do you mean that these operators may not be used _at all_, or, that they may be used, but only if the result isn't saved to a variable, e.g. `while r*r<n*10e20:r+=1` - fairly trivial. Also, you might consider reducing the required output to 10^8 or so. First, because 10^10 is larger than 2^31, and second, because it will take a while to increment that high.

Comment: Why would you _ever_ want to "change" any variable at all? You imperative guys have strange ways of thinking...

Comment: Are we allowed to do, say, `i=1`? That is, can we initialise a variable that will then be incremented?

Comment: @leftaroundabout 'static variable' is self-contradictive.

Comment: @Ourous - oh sorry, missed that part.  If the function in itself changes the value of any variable, it is not allowed.

Comment: @primo - I'll reduce it to 10^8, but answers with 10^10 will still be allowed

Comment: @GlenO - "If you wish, you may initialize a variable by setting it to 0." You can do i=0, but not i=1.  If you needed i=1, you could always do i=0;i++;

Comment: I am flagging to close this question. To much radical changes to the question. You should actually get this question validated through Sandbox or else you would frustrate people investing effort to answer.

Comment: Reducing the number of required digits is meaningless without time/memory limits. My code can handle 5 digits, but my machine doesn't have enough RAM.

Answer (score 13):

### Python 66

```
print'%.0f'%reduce(lambda a,b:abs(a)+1e10j,range(-2,input())).real
```

### Output

```
>>> print'%.0f'%reduce(lambda a,b:abs(a)+1e10j,range(-2,input())).real
121
110000000000
>>> print'%.0f'%reduce(lambda a,b:abs(a)+1e10j,range(-2,input())).real
1000
316227766017
```

> This solution uses [Spiral of Theodorus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_Theodorus) on a complex plane to achieve the result.

Comment: I think that will need to be wrapped in `int(...*1e10)`, otherwise very nice. Although, taking `abs` of a complex value is more or less `sqrt` in disguise.

Comment: @primo I don't think you're allowed the `*1e10` ...

Comment: @primo: Instead of multiplying by 1e10, I took a bit different route. And though I agree that abs may be sqrt in disguise, yet I feel its completely legal as currently stated in the problem.

Comment: I see a downvote, and its quite depressing. I had high hope for this answer, so any one who downvoted, please leave back a comment.

Comment: This doesn't follow the new clarification.  Sorry about invalidating your answer, but I meant to say that these functions were not allowed at all, not just to modify a variable.

Comment: @iggyvolz: I am really surprised that you keep on expanding your question and adding more restrictions. People invest time and effort to write an answer and you can;t expect them to be psycic.

Comment: I tried running as a py file and it says syntax error. In the interpreter it runs OK. Output without %d is 1.1e+11 and with %d output is 1099999999.

Comment: @bacchusbeale: `I tried running as a py file and it says syntax error.`, not sure what error you are getting. This runs fine in [ideone](http://ideone.com/bXAYkY). Regarding, your o/p as 1099999999, there was a rounding issue which I have now fixed.

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 184 characters

The following Python solution uses only the increment operator and no other arithmetic operators at all. However, with the required precision (10 digits), it takes an impossibly long time to run. You can test it with lower precision (3 digits) by reducing `1e20` to `1e6`.

```python
import sys;t=0
for _ in range(int(sys.argv[1])):
 for _ in range(int(1e20)):t+=1
q=0
while 1:
 z=0
 for _ in range(q):
  for _ in range(q):z+=1
 if z>=t:break
 q+=1
print(q)
```

Ungolfed:

```python
import sys

# t = N * 100000000000000000000 (magnitude of twice the precision)
t = 0
for _ in range(int(sys.argv[1])):
    for _ in range(int(1e20)):
        t += 1
q = 0
while True:
    # z = q * q
    z = 0
    for _ in range(q):
        for _ in range(q):
            z += 1
    if z >= t:
        break
    q += 1
print(q)
```

Comment: I clarified the question, you can do it to as many digits as you want (at least 5).

I'm not familiar with python, but I'm assuming that int() is just a type caster?  If so, that is fine because it doesn't change the value of the number.

Comment: @iggyvolz: Right, you need that to convert the string argument value (specified on the command line) to an integer. A plain function wouldn't need that.

Answer (score 3):

### Fortran 73

```
read*,t;s=0;do while(abs(s*s/1e10-t)>1e-10);s=s+1;enddo;print*,s/1e5;end
```

Might take a loooong to actually determine an answer for certain values, but it'll work for sure. While I use `*` and `-`, *these are not changing any values*, only the `s=s+1` actually changes anything.

Comment: Wow, guess I didn't think about using operators for changing static values.  That's perfectly fine and +1 (if I had 15 reputation to upvote)

Comment: This uses the `*` operator, which is pretty clearly not permitted. Or am I somehow misunderstanding the given restrictions?

Comment: @GregHewgill: OP states, *without using any mathematical operators to change the number*; these operators are not changing any values.

Comment: I guess then I don't understand what is meant by *the number* - which number? Just the one that is the input to the program?

Comment: @GregHewgill: We're to compute `sqrt(t)` by only incrementing some other variable, `s`, until `s*s=t`; my assumption is that "number" means `s`.

Comment: But that's still using the `*` operator to change a number, you're just not saving the result anywhere. If the OP wanted to simply disallow *assignments* (other than `s=s+1`), then why mention all the disallowed arithmetic operators?

Comment: @GregHewgill: Nothing I did is explicitly against the specs, though I agree I'm bending it a little. OP said my answer is perfectly fine (because he *didn't think about using operators for changing static values*), I'm content with that.

Comment: So then what does *changing static values* mean? The usual definition of *static* means that something doesn't change. What are you changing that doesn't change?

Comment: @GregHewgill: I think that the question is poorly specified; this answer of mine reflects the poor nature of the question by abusing one aspect of the rules (that you can only change a variable by incrementing it). Any analysis of this particular answer is moot, IMO.

Comment: This doesn't follow the new clarification.  Sorry about invalidating your answer, but I meant to say that these functions were not allowed at all, not just to modify a variable.

Yeah, sorry about my earlier comment, I was half asleep when I made that.

Comment: @iggyvolz: Changing the rules ~20 hours later is bad form. Please do not do that and use the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/proposed-question-sandbox-mark-xiii) to work out the kinks in your problem instead.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 26 bytes

```
q~,1e20,m*,:N!{)_,_m*,N<}g
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/) Paste the **Code**, type the desired integer in **Input** and click **Run**. Before you do, I suggest changing `1e10` to `1e4` though.

The [Java interpreter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/files/?source=navbar) handles `1e6` with input “2” in about 15 seconds. `1e20` will require a *huge* amount of RAM.

#### Examples

```
$ cjam <(echo 'q~,1e2,m*,:N!{)_,_m*,N<}g') <<< 4; echo
20
$ cjam <(echo 'q~,1e2,m*,:N!{)_,_m*,N<}g') <<< 2; echo
15
$ cjam <(echo 'q~,1e4,m*,:N!{)_,_m*,N<}g') <<< 4; echo
200
$ cjam <(echo 'q~,1e4,m*,:N!{)_,_m*,N<}g') <<< 2; echo
142
$ cjam <(echo 'q~,1e6,m*,:N!{)_,_m*,N<}g') <<< 4; echo
2000
$ cjam <(echo 'q~,1e6,m*,:N!{)_,_m*,N<}g') <<< 2; echo
1415
```

#### Background

Since we're not allowed mathematical operators to change numbers, we're going to use setwise operators to change arrays.

The code starts by "multiplying" the input (“i”) by 1e20, but without any  actual multiplication. Instead, we push an array containing “i” integers, an array containing 1e20 integers, take their cartesian product and compute its length.

Then, we push zero and increment until the product of the integer by itself (calculated as above) is no longer smaller than `i * 1e20`. This causes the square root to be rounded up.

#### How it works

```
q~     " Read for STDIN and interpret. ";
,      " Push an array containing that many integers. ";
1e20,  " Push the array [ 0   …   1e20 - 1]. ";
m*,:N  " Get the length of the cartesian product and save it in “N”. ";
!      " Logical NOT. Since the input is a positive integer, this pushes 0. " ;
{      " ";
  )    " Increment the integer on the stack.";
  _,   " Push an array containing that many integers. ";
  _m*, " Get the length of the cartesian product of the array by itself. ";
  N<   " If the product is smaller than the target value, push 1; otherwise push 0. ";
}g     " Repeat the loop if the result was 1. ";
```

Answer (score 1):

## Cobra - 62

**Posted before the third edit, no longer valid.**

Not only is it short, but it should be overflow-free if `n < Decimal.maxValue`

```
def f(n)
    r,e=0d,10000000000
    while r/e*r/e<n,r+=1
    print r
```

Comment: But you used `r/e*r/e`, which is clearly a non-`++` math operator...

Comment: @nneonneo this was posted before the third edit, and I haven't changed it yet

Answer (score 0):

### Scala, 117

```
val z=BigInt(readLine+"0000000000")
print(Stream.from(1)find(x=>(BigInt(0)/:Stream.fill(x,x)(1).flatten){_+_}>=z)get)
```

Doesn't finish in a reasonable amount of time, even for 2 as input, but it does work. You may notice that I'm doing `_+_`, but that only ever adds 1, and Scala doesn't have a `++` operator anyway. I could save two characters by replacing the inner Stream with List, but then it would run out of memory. As written, I think it scales only in processing time, not memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 124 bytes

It's an exhaustive algorithm. It just tries numbers until the square of that number is bigger than the "goal" number (which is the input times 1E`number of decimals` squared (10.000 for a 2 decimal result). Then it prints that last number.

```
for(;$a++<$z=$argv[1];)for(;$$a++<1e6;)$g++;for(;$b++<$g;$i=$x=0)for(;$i++<$b;)for($j=0;$j++<$b;)if(++$x>=$g)break 3;echo$b;
```

Run like this (`-d` added for aesthetic reasons only):

```
php -d error_reporting=32757 -r 'for(;$a++<$z=$argv[1];)for(;$$a++<1e6;)$g++;for(;$b++<$g;$i=$x=0)for(;$i++<$b;)for($j=0;$j++<$b;)if(++$x>=$g)break 3;echo"$b\n";' 2
```

Don't recommend trying this out with anything more than 3 decimals or a number above 10.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 70 bytes

```
s i|r<-[1..i]=foldl1(.)[(+1)|j<-r,k<-r]
f i=[j-1|j<-[0..],s j 0>=i]!!1
```

`f` gives the integer square root by finding the largest number whose square is less than or equal to the input. The squaring function `s i` increments by one for every element of an `(i,i)` matrix. (Typed on phone so might have typos).

Answer (score 0):

## x86-64 Assembly Code, 22 bytes

No operators or function calls, as per the rules.

```
// Int from stack -> st0
fild 8(%rsp)
// sqrt(st0) -> st0
fsqrt
ret
```

Expects argument pushed onto the stack, then call this function, like so:

```
push $2
call a
```

The result is saved onto the register stack (`%st0`). Tested on MinGW64.