# principal square root without resorting to built‑ins

Tags: code-golf, math

Write a square root function taking a single input – positive, negative or sign‑less (zero is sign‑less) – that outputs its approximate principal square root, correct up to six decimal places past the decimal point (truncate after the sixth decimal place).
Employing scientific notation (`1E3` = `1 × 10³` = 100) or similar is not allowed.

You are forbidden from using *any* built‑in power‑related functions, including but not limited to

- `Math.pow(n, 0.5)`
- `sqrt(2)`
- `root(n, 2)`
- `n ** 0.5`
- `exp(ln(n) ∕ 2)` (the exponentiation function is forbidden, logarithms and division are allowed)

This means that you have to implement your own method for finding the principal square root.
Two common [methods](https://en.WikiPedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) are the Babylonian/bisector method and Newton’s method, but feel free to create your own!

Output can be either printed to the console or returned, your choice.
Examples:

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 |
| 7 | 2.645751 |
| 5.0625 | 2.25 |
| −15 | 3.872983 i |
| −9 | 3 i |

Comment: Is e^x allowed? (I'm guessing not)

Comment: While [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73/14215) doesn't ban power functions, there are enough answers there that don't use them to call this one a dupe, IMO.

Comment: There's also http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/30253/calculate-the-square-root-only-using

Comment: Is an xth root function power-related?

Comment: Also, 6 decimal places is somewhat ambiguous, do you mean six significant figures? Otherwise this becomes dramatically more complicated given a 50 digit input.

Comment: "Do X without Y" challenges are [generally a bad idea](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/20260), and this one hits the usual pitfalls.

Comment: @quartata - no, that is not allowed as that is power (^)

Comment: @ThomasKwa - wouldn't xth root be equivalent to n^(1/x), which is power

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman - I'm not sure exactly what you mean. How is six decimal places ambiguous? If you have 1.2345678901, then you would truncate to 1.234567

Comment: Try, for example `500000000000000000` as input, the output should be `707106781.18654752` ish, is the result then `707106000`? Can it be in scientific notation? These general floating point issues make a good case for using the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31625).

Comment: With this definition, even division would be disallowed, as `x/y` is equal to `xy^(-1)`.

Comment: I voted to close this as unclear and the other one as a dupe. The old challenge was broken (all of the answers were just `**.5`), whereas this has a better chance of being a good challenge. I am concerned, like @xnor, about the viability of a challenge of this type, however.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman - the output cannot be in scientific notation. Your example would have an output of 707106781.186547

Comment: @LegionMammal978 - I don't mean to be so restrictive. I just want to find an objective way to ensure that nobody uses trivial answers that let them not write or not implement an algorithm to find the square root. This challenge is essentially to write the shortest code to find the square root of a number like the system would, in that a system cannot use built ins because it *is* the built in. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @Dopapp I think this is an interesting idea for a challenge, although there are some parts to it that are unclear. Would you mind if I were to post the same challenge but with clearer rules? (I won't do it if you'd like to do it yourself)

Comment: Go for it @DrGreenEggsandIronMan! I'll be looking out for your version :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## c (function), 166

Now with complex numbers.  Uses the [GCC complex number extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Complex.html).

Straightforward golfing of the famous [Fast inverse square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) method.  This method gives `1/sqrt(n)`, so we simply multiply this by `n` to give `sqrt(n)`:

```c
#include <complex.h>
#define M y*=1.5-n*y*y/2
i;_Complex float f(float m){float y,n;n=m>0?m:-m;y=n;i=0x5f3759df-*(int*)&y/2;y=*(float*)&i;M;M;M;return m>0?y*n:y*n*I;}
```

The [famous snippet of Quake code](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake-III-Arena/blob/master/code/game/q_math.c#L552) only does one iteration of Newton's method, which gives a fairly inaccurate answer.  Three iterations here seems to be enough for 6 decimal places, at least for the testcases.

[Try it online.](https://ideone.com/XT2CbV)

Comment: Isn't this not-your-IP and should thus be CW? Or could you at least link to the source file (there are github repos of Quake source)?

Comment: @cat OK - CWed and github URL added.